# Does macos come built in with the clang compiler or is built in with the xcode ide?

Tags: c++, c, macos, clang

I just started got into coding and was curious if the clang compiler is built into the macos as of 2020 or if it is built in the XCode IDE? Is there anyway to confirm or check?

Comment: Relevant answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/181953

Comment: as you can read here https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html clang is the default C/C++ compiler of macos

Comment: Clang and Xcode are not distributed in macOS distributions but are available as downloads from Apple. Xcode command-line developer tools can be downloaded, including Clang but without the full Xcode installation, by typing `xcode-select -install` in a Terminal window. The full Xcode is available at [https://developer.apple.com/download/](https://developer.apple.com/download/) (free account required).

Answer (score 2):

Clang and Xcode are not distributed in macOS distributions but are available as downloads from Apple. Xcode command-line developer tools can be downloaded, including Clang but without the full Xcode installation, by typing `xcode-select -install` in a Terminal window. The full Xcode is available at https://developer.apple.com/download/ (free account required).

Comment: Also, there are placeholder executables for common developer tools (e.g. `cc`) which, when run, prompt the user to install the Command Line Tools automatically.